# Parsing a SOAP notification

Tags: python, parsing, soap

I have a device that periodically sends SOAP notifications to an HTTP server that I have running in my computer. The notifications look like the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <Notify>
            <DeviceNotification message= "
                    <NotificationEvent NotificationType="Location">
                            <ComputerLocation changedOn="1369757031051">
                            </ComputerLocation>
                    </NotificationEvent>
                "/>
        </Notify>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

It's a SOAP envelope that contains XML representation for an instance of type DeviceNotification.

I don't really know how to treat these notifications (as if my program was a server? a client?). The notification looks more like a response to a command, but I'm actually not calling any remote service (The machine that sends notifications has a web interface where I input "*destination for the notifications: this ip, this port*" and it starts sending them)  I'm not sure if the SOAP in the notification is totally correct either.

I've tried several SOAP libraries and such... I think the closest thing I've been able to achieve is with [spyne](http://spyne.io/) (or maybe is just a mirage, and I think that because it outputs more stuff than other libreries)

```
class DeviceNotification(ComplexModel):
        ___namespace__ = ""
        pass

class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(DeviceNotification, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def Notify(message):
        logging.warn("CHECKPOINT")
        print "message: %s" % message
        return ["foobarbaz"]

if __name__=='__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    PORT=7171
    application = Application([HelloWorldService],
                tns="",
                in_protocol=HttpRpc(validator='soft'),
                out_protocol=JsonDocument()
            )
    wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)
    server = make_server('', PORT, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

But the *Notify* function never gets called. I get:

```
192.168.1.33 - - [28/May/2013 21:16:52] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 130
DEBUG:spyne.server.wsgi:Method name: '{}'
DEBUG:spyne.protocol.http:  header : {'soapaction': ['Notify'], 'host': ['niuyorker.jome:7171'], 'user_agent': ['Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1']
```

And this is the closest thing I get. Is that SOAP message correct? If it is, and whether this should be treated as a request to a server (my server) or as a response (therefore, my application would be a client). It would also help if anybody knew where to find an example with Python and SOAP a bit more complex than adding two numbers or say 'Hello' a number of times?

I suppose I could always use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to parse the whole SOAP message, but I'd like to do it a bit more "professionally" if possible. Just in case you haven't noticed: I'm a total newbie to SOAP services! **:)**

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

It looks like the message part should actually be escaped XML, which... well... it's what I was actually getting from the beginning but (newbie as I am) I escaped it so it would look prettier in the question. The real is:

```
 <soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap-env:body>
  <notify>
   <notification message='&lt;NotificationEvent NotificationType="Location"&gt;&lt;DeviceLocation changedOn="1369074622065"&gt;&lt;/DeviceLocation&gt;&lt;/NotificationEvent&gt;'>
   </notification>
  </notify>
 </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

I do have the WSDL. Using [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) I've been able to create instances of 'ComputerLocation' type, something like:

```
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> url="file:///tmp/service.wsdl"
>>> c=Client(url)
>>> c.factory.create('DeviceLocation')
(DeviceLocation){
   _changedOn = ""
 }
```

But that's pretty much all I've been able to do.

To be honest, I still don't know whether I need a server or a client...

Comment: Are you trying to set up a raw TCP server, as your explanation describes, or an HTTP server, as your sample code does?

Comment: Sorry, HTTP (editing in 3,2,1...)

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm not sure that bare `Notify` is a valid child of the Body. And I don't think the multi-line string full of XML is valid either. But… I honestly can't find any SOAP 1.1 tools around on my computer or online. (This is a really ancient technology to be learning as a newbie in 2013!) So, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I don't think just "use lxml" will help here. When I just toss it at either the DOM API or the ETree API, I get an exception about the invalid XML. However… using lxml and BeautifulSoup together might work. Tossing your example at `BeautifulSoup(x, ['lxml', 'xml'])` recovers… well, I'm not sure if it's the intended structure, but a _usable_ structure, with the contents of the `message` string parsed as XML and attached as a child of `DeviceNotification` (although there are some left over epilog strings, like `"/&gt;`, that you'll have to ignore).

Comment: @abarnert: BeautifulSoup seems to at least provide a navigable structure Thx! :)

Comment: Can you give a second (different) example so we can see what does and doesn't vary between messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `in_protocol=HttpRpc` instead of `in_protocol=Soap11`.

The [`HttpRpc` protocol](http://spyne.io/docs/2.9/reference/protocol/http.html#spyne.protocol.http.HttpRpc) is defined simply as:

> The so-called ReST-ish HttpRpc protocol implementation.

While it's not entirely clear what this means, it's a good bet that it *doesn't* attempt to parse SOAP 1.1 messages to find the commands, as that's not about as far from REST-ish as possible.

---

Having gotten past this, and given your updated (correct) example:

That parses as valid XML, and it's in a valid SOAP 1.1 envelope.

But it's still not *good* SOAP. The contents of the body aren't namespaced, and aren't structured objects with parameters. In fact, the entire content is one generic XML tree, and the *actual* content is another generic XML tree that's stored in escaped form as an attribute of a node in the outer tree.

From the looks of your one example, I'd guess that the URL path is always `/`, and the SOAP structure is always just a single `Notify` directly inside the SOAP envelope. Sure, if you fight with your framework enough, you can probably get it to dispatch on `Notify`, but then all your messages will end up in the same place anyway, so… why bother? What you probably want to dispatch on, if anything, is something inside the embedded XML, like the `NotificationType`.

If those guesses are right, take the most familiar web server you know how to use—you don't even really need WSGI; just write a trivial handler for `http.server.HTTPServer` if you want—and route every message to the same code, which does just enough parsing to get to the `NotificationEvent` objects and dispatch from there. Something like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def handle_location(nevent):
    clocation = nevent.find('ComputerLocation')
    changed_on = clocation.attrib['changedOn']
    location = clocation.text
    # do something with this info

def handle_other_thing(nevent):
    # whatever

handlers = {'Location': handle_location,
            'OtherThing': handle_other_thing }

et = ET.fromstring(body)
for notification in et.iter('notification'):
    message = ET.fromstring(notification.attrib['message'])
    for nevent in message.iter('NotificationEvent'):
        ntype = nevent.attrib['NotificationType']
        handlers[ntype](nevent)
```

It sounds like you may have WSDL for the lowest-level fields within the `NotificationEvent`, so you can use `suds` in place of manually parsing the etree once you get to that level, if it makes your life easier or makes your code more flexible.

And of course you'll want to add some error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the help, abanert. I also tried Soap11, but then it gives validation errors.

Comment: @BorrajaX: That's a new problem, and the problem is that it's not valid XML, and therefore can't be valid SOAP 1.1. If the problem is just that you've pre-processed it in some way that breaks it… don't do that. If the original data are already broken, you'll need to figure out some way to fix them up, or figure out the almost-but-not XML language well enough that you can write your own parser (e.g., with pyparsing).

Comment: I have just updated my question... Maybe that'll help clarifying something... Thanks for the help, though! :)

Comment: Having read up a bit on the spyne library, I think abarnert is on the right track here. With the updated XML in your question you've at least got valid input. My only concern would be the lack of namespace. What exactly are the validation errors you're getting? Maybe add those to the question too.

Comment: For abarnert y @James Holderness... I gave up trying to do this in a SOAP-y way... I'm just gonna go with the xml/lxml solution... It works decently enough. A pity, but I guess I chose a baaaad example to start learning SOAP **:)** Thank you very much for your ideas!

Comment: @BorrajaX: As I said somewhere or other, I'm not sure learning SOAP 1.1 is the best use of your time in 2013 anyway…

Comment: Yeah, and I also learned that the thing that is sending this "half-baked" SOAP is going to be upgraded to JSON... So I gave up... :)

Answer (score 1):

The XML that you've provided is complete nonsense. I don't believe you'll find any XML parser that will be capable of processing that. Everything inside the `message` attribute of the `DeviceNotification` element would need to be escaped for that XML to be well formed.

First off, you can't have an left angle bracket in an attribute value. That's clearly a well-formedness constraint violation: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#CleanAttrVals

And even if you got past that, you obviously can't have a double quote in the attribute when the attribute value is already enclosed in double quotes. The open quote of the `NotificationType` attribute is going to appear to the parser to be the close quote of the `message` attribute.

Frankly, I think the best you can do is try and extract the data from this with a regex of some sort. It's not XML, and thus it's not SOAP.

**Update**

With the updates in the question it's clear now that some of the awfulness of that XML was just a formatting issue so everything I've said above doesn't really apply. The concept of embedding XML in an attribute is still ridiculous though.

In answer to the question, are you a server or a client, technically you're the client. However, because this is a notification pattern, you're the receiver of messages rather than the sender (which would typically be the case for a client).

Usually for this kind of scenario I would expect you to send a message to the server requesting notifications and providing an endpoint at which those notifications would be received. In this case you've done all that through a separate web interface.

So all that remains then is for you to receive the messages, and in that role you're acting more like a server. I may be wrong about this, but I would think you should be using your SOAP library's server functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But now I'm curious: Assuming it was well formed, and not a problem with outputting it on the screen, what is this? How would I parse that? I'm asking because to ask the question in stack-overflow I might have used a decode function so it kind of looked better *0_0* (sorry)

Comment: @BorrajaX: This is very clearly SOAP 1.1. (Well, it's either a broken attempt at SOAP 1.1, or SOAP 1.1 that you mangled in formatting.) The namespace you reference is the SOAP 1.1 namespace (click [this link](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) to see it), and the top-level tag names are only used by pre-1.2 SOAP.

Comment: Even if it was mangled in the formatting, and the `data` content was properly escaped, this is a terrible example of SOAP. Who takes an XML fragment, and then embeds it as an escaped attribute? Why are there no namespaces on the elements in the SOAP body? This looks like something created by someone that knew nothing about SOAP or XML trying to produce something that kind of looked like SOAP. If it came with a WSDL of some sort it might be worth trying to parse as SOAP, otherwise if you can get an XML parser to read it, just parse out the elements you're interested in and ignore the rest.

Comment: @James Holderness: I have a WSDL for the *ComputerLocation* elements, not for the outermost ones... Would that help for anything?

Comment: @JamesHolderness: Honestly, how often have you _ever_ seen a good example of SOAP 1.1? (Especially after SOAP 1.2 came out, which meant anyone writing new SOAP 1.1 was either confused by the cleaned-up namespacing in 1.2, or so unable to think about XML that they were completely dependent on a pre-made library…)

Comment: @BorrajaX: Well, if the `ComputerLocation` always has a single attribute and no children, it would be pretty silly to manually parse all the complicated stuff, and then use the WSDL for the trivial bit at the leaf…

Comment: @abarnert There's bad and then there is ridiculous. :)

Comment: @BorrajaX It's possible that was just a simplified example, in which case the WSDL would at least tell you what else to expect. But I'm not sure that would be of any use in processing this content with a SOAP library. I'd still recommend parsing it manually (with an XML library if possible), and just use the WSDL as a reference.

Comment: The thing is that I can get some other stuff more complex than *ComputerLocation*, so I wanted to try doing something generic (or as generic as possible). I just edited the question... maybe it'll clarify something? Thanks for all the help, btw!